# Firestore : get all files ( only specify ids)

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I need to retrieve all file with specify id

my firestore ( structure )

```
users/user1/img1 -> [ fileId = img1  , file = img1.jpg ]
users/user2/img2 -> [ fileId = img2  , file = img2.jpg ]
users/user3/img3 -> [ fileId = img3  , file = img3.jpg ]
```

I find in the document , the 'getAll' methods ( https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/Firestore_.html#getAll )

but with their example, it don't work.

My code

```
import storage  from "@react-native-firebase/storage";

let docRef1 = storage().doc('/users/user1/img1');
let docRef2 = storage().doc('/users/user2/img2');
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // Now we get the references of these images
    storage().getAll(docRef1, docRef2).then(docs => {
        resolve()
    }).catch(function(error) {
        // Handle any errors
        console.log('error', error)
        reject()
    });
```

My error:

```
TypeError: (0, _storage.default)().doc is not a function. (In '(0, _storage.default)().doc('/products/3799569030005-1.jpg')', '(0, _storage.default)().doc' is undefined)
```

Update 1: after the post of Frank van Puffelen
I modify my code to test with an id

```
import firestore from "@react-native-firebase/firestore";
let docRef1 = firestore().collection('users').doc('user1/img1');
let docRef2 = firestore().doc('/users/user1/img1');
// use with docRef1  or docRef2
docRef2.get().then(docSnapshots => {
        console.log('AA1 docSnapshots data', docSnapshots.data())
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log('AA2 err', err)
    })
// error for the docRef1 and docref2 =>  Error: firebase.firestore().doc(*) 'documentPath' must point to a document.
```

Answer (score 1):

By calling `storage()` you're using the API for Firebase Storage, which accesses files in Cloud Storage (storing files). But then you say you want to access documents in Cloud Firestore, which is a noSQL document database.

While both Firestore and Storage can be access through Firebase SDKs, they are completely separate and the API for one has nothing to do with the other. If you want to access Firestore, use `firebase.firestore()...` (or just `firestore()` on react-native-firebase).

---

The `getAll()` method you linked to exists in the Node.js SDK for Firestore. It does not exist in the JavaScript/Web SDK nor in the react-native-firebase wrapper. In those SDKs, you will have to call `get` on each individual `DocumentReference` object, or you can use an [`in` query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#in_not-in_and_array-contains-any) on `FieldPath.documentId()`.

The first approach (as that is closest to the code in your question):

```
let docRef1 = firestore().doc('/users/user1/img1');
let docRef2 = firestore().doc('/users/user2/img2');
Promise.all([docRef1.get(), docRef2.get()])
  .then((docSnapshots) => {
    console.log(docSnapshots[0].data(), docSnapshots[1].data());
  });
```

Comment: helllo thanks for your response. I test your example but it's not working for me.
i updated my post

Comment: That's a different problem: your `firestore().collection('users').doc('user1/img1');` points to a top-level collection `users`, the `user` document in that collection, and then the `img1` subcollection in that document. So you'll need to use the `collection` call for it.